# New Website redirecting to another website of mine (not the base)

Tags: redirect, magento-2.2.1, multi-website

I've recently just created a new Website, Store view and Store for my website. And I have set the store specific url in Configuration -> General -> Web. I have contacted my hosting company to point an IP address to my website as well. However when I try to access the new website, it redirects me to another one, which is not the base one.

My next logical step was to include this snippet of code into my index.php

```
case 'mywebsite.be':
case 'www.mywebsite.be':
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'mywebsitebe';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'mywebsite';
    break;
```

There is still no change...
One thing I have noticed though is that whenever I type in the address bar mywebsite.be it reroutes me to http://mywebsite.com. Then when I rewrite the url to http://mywebsite.be it shows me that this website cannot be reached.

Has anyone else gone through something similar?

Comment: check whether there is any addondomain in your cpanel

Comment: The issue is that I do not have access to cpanel as I use a hosting company

Comment: without access cpanel, no one cant help you. sorry.

first post website url

Comment: You need to have a separate vhost setup in cPanel/Apache/NGINX to register the new URL and to point it to the correct store view. Without this, the DNS will route it to whatever default/running vhost is setup and route it through that instead.

Comment: Okay, I will tell them this. Thanks for the advice